# Get Nth parent of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the the Nth parent of multiple elements?

Right now I do it like this:

```
var winners = THUMBNAILS.find(".tournament-winner:contains(" + filter + ")");
var filteredThumbnails = winners.parent().parent().parent().parent().clone();
```

this does work.

But when I try to do it like:

```
var filteredThumbnails = winners.parents().eq(3).clone();
```

It only gets the thumbnail (great grandfather) of just one element in the `winners` variable.

Is there any easier way to get Nth parent of multiple elements?

Comment: Can you share HTML? There might be a easier way

Comment: try `closest` (if the element you are after has a distinct class)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
//Create empty object
var filteredThumbnails = $(); 

//Iterate and target parent 
winners.each(function(){
  filteredThumbnails.add($(this).parents().eq(3).clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

write a `.map()` or `.forEach()` function on the winners array.
example:

```
filteredThumbnails =  winners.map(winner => winner.parent().parent().parent().parent().clone());
```

Comment: There is no need for `.map()` or `.forEach()` since `winners.parent().parent().parent().parent().clone()` already accomplishes the same.

Comment: @Drago, what if winners is an array of elements that do not share a common ancestor ? How does going to parent node accomplish looping an array of elements?

Comment: In my case they all share common ancestors.

Comment: Then kindly explain your case properly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` on return value of parents.

`$.parents` return an array.

Let's say you have the following HTML and you want to get divs with ids `parentN`. which is the third parent. After that you can convert the elements to an array. Alternatively, you can create a function like this and use it in different places.

then you have to get every fourth element of the `parents`

```js
function getNthParents(obj, N) { 
    return obj.parents().filter(index => !((index + 1) % N)).toArray();
}
nthParents = getNthParents($('.thumbnail'), 3)
console.log(nthParents)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent1'>
  <div>
    <div>
        <div class='thumbnail'>
           
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='parent2'>
  <div>
    <div>
       <div class='thumbnail'>
           
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='parent3'>
  <div>
    <div>
       <div class='thumbnail'>
           
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check you snippet

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if you shared your html.

As i am not sure what you are trying to achieve...but

Another way of getting up multiple parent levels of the element you are targeting, 
which **doesn't have a unique name** would be like below. which will traverse up until it finds a parent which has an id which starts with "parent".

```
winners.parents("[id^=parent]")
```

Although i would give them a generic css class to travel up to rather than this.